# How should I design my table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to create a table for operating on data, which has been provided to me like this:

```
col1    col2        col3
1       < 3         50%
2       < 5         50%
3       < 10        50%
1       5>RC >=3    25%
2       10>RC >=5   25%
3       20>RC >=10  25%
1       >=5         0%
2       >=10        0%
3       >=20        0%
```

A user of the system would be passing a number, which is present in `col2` and `col1` above. Let's say that the user passed 7 for col2 and 1 for col1. Business requirement is that I should return the user the following row

```
1       >=5         0%
```

Roughly speaking, it means that I checked the value in `col2`, and noticed that it is `>=5`, which my input data fits.

I was thinking of splitting `col2` across two columns - one for storing the number and the other for operator. Something like this:

```
col1    col2        col3    col4
1       3           50%     <
2       5           50%     <
3       10          50%     <
1       5>RC >=3    25%
2       10>RC >=5   25%
3       20>RC >=10  25%
1       5           0%      >=
2       10          0%      >=
3       20          0%      >=
```

Thsi way, I will be able to write queries for addressing queries based on data in first and last three columns (though I have not running queries right now, I just did dry run). What I am not able to figure out so far is - How to address the data in rows 4,5,6? You can ignore the `RC` part in those rows, as I can certainly do away with it, as I am concerned with the numeric range for my queries.

I tried splitting the data for rows 4,5,6 in 2 rows each, something like:

```
1       3           25%     >=
1       5           25%     <
2       5           25%     >=
2       10          25%     <
3       10          25%     >=
3       20          25%     <
```

But, I see an imminent issue here, when it comes to retrieving the data. Let's say that user paased `col2 = 7 AND col1 = 1`. Now, I should have got only one row,that is row number 7 in the first table in my question, but I am also getting an additional row (1st row in last table, where I was splitting data for BETWEEN conditions)

Can anyone suggest me a better approach for storing this data so that my requierment can be achieved?

SQLFiddle demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2d90/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest, that you should just split col2 in two columns - lower and higher bound, replacing not existing bound, for example, with NULL. It will look something like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+----+
|col1|col2_lb|col2_hb|col3|
+----+-------+-------+----+
|1   |NULL   |3      |50% |
+----+-------+-------+----+
|2   |NULL   |5      |50% |
+----+-------+-------+----+
|3   |NULL   |10     |50% |
+----+-------+-------+----+
|1   |3      |5      |25% |
+----+-------+-------+----+
|... |...    |...    |... |
+----+-------+-------+----+
|1   |5      |NULL   |0%  |
+----+-------+-------+----+
```

Using this structure, you'll be able to find needed row with simple query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_TABLE t 
WHERE t.col1 = :VAL1 
      AND NVL(t.col2_lb,:VAL2) <= :VAL2
      AND NVL(t.col2_hb,:VAL2+1) > :VAL2
```

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail I was already trying this approach of splitting data into separate columns, but I was stuck due to a simple mistake I had made in my query. Your query showed me that, and it's working as intended now! Much Thanks!